# Update query with where clause taking time on clustered index with millions of data

Tags: sql-server

```
    CREATE TABLE Test_Table
    (
        Id             INT             NOT NULL,
        Column2        VARCHAR(64)     NOT NULL,
        Column3        VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
        Column4        VARCHAR(64)     NOT NULL,
        Column5        VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
        Column6        VARCHAR(256)    NOT NULL,
        Column7        INT             NOT NULL,
        Column8        VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
        column9        INT             NOT NULL,
        Column10       DATETIME        NULL,
        Flag           BIT             NULL
    )

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_Test_Table ON Test_Table
    (
        Column1,
        Column2,
        Column3,
        Column4,
        Column5,
        Column6
    )
```

inputs : @flag(BIT) , @now (varchar(10)),  @reason (varchar(10)), @column4Input (VARCHAR)

```
    UPDATE  TOP (100) Test_Table
    SET     Flag = @flag,
            Column10 = @now,
            Column8 = @reason
    WHERE   Id BETWEEN @startId AND ISNULL(@endId, @startId)
            AND ISNULL(@column4Input, Column4) = Column4
            AND (Flag <> @flag OR Flag IS NULL)
```

I've a table Test_Table and then I've a query that updates(where query with Id, Column4 and Flag) few columns of the table. This update operation is costly operation for a table with millions of data. Query plan shows 48% time for SEEK and 48% time for update. *How can I improve performance of the update query?*

- Will adding a nonclustered index improve the performance of the query?
- will iterating over Ids instead of using Between help?

Comment: A clustered index that wide is going to cause issues. I definitely wouldn't add a nonclustered index before fixing that. Any case, an NCI is going to be a waste of time here because of the `ISNULL`s.

Comment: @Charlieface Why is a 6 field clustered index problematic? I've adopted a general 5x5 rule from what I've read on Brent Ozar's blog (5 indexes max per table, 5 columns max per index). Though this is just a basic rule of thumb I follow, it's not set in stone. I also never really had a need to add so many fields to my clustered index before either so I'm not experienced to know if there's anything special about the clustered index (as opposed to a nonclustered index) in this regard, but I'd be interested if there was a specific reason you advise against it?

Comment: @J.D. The CI is the row identifier, so every column in it is in every NCI by design. This can cause perf problems when doing DML, especially when they're all VARCHAR.

Comment: @Charlieface Ah true good point. I wasn't thinking about it from that perspective but yes that's important to consider. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is `Id` not unique on its own?...also I'm not sure how you're getting a **seek** operation when your predicates (`Id` and `Flag`) aren't part of the index, and `Column4` is in the middle of the index (unless you have other indexes the query plan is using). In any case, please update your answer with the **Actual Execution Plan** (which you can upload on [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)) so that we can see exactly what your query is doing, where the bottlenecks are, and how to improve performance.

Lacking that, the most minimal change I can generically suggest is creating a **nonclustered index** on `Id`, `Column4`, `Flag` including `Column10`, `Column8`.

Example query: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Test_Table_Id_Column4_Flag ON (Id, Column4, Flag) INCLUDE (Column10, Column8)`